# What kind of data should be in $data argument in the wp_update_attachment_metadata() function?

Tags: wordpress, function

I need to update "_wp_attachment_metadata" in wppostmeta tabele of image that was copy&paste to new localization.

Since WP documentation isn't clear for me, I'd like to ask what should I input to $data argument?

```
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $post_id, $data );
```

$post_id is pretty clear, I can take it from database. What about $data?

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_attachment_metadata

---

EDIT

I have tried this (98 is post_id/attachment-page id)

```
$data = wp_get_attachment_metadata( 98 ); 
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $post_id, $data );
```

but it doesn't works I've also tried something like:

```
`while ($row = $post_id->fetch_assoc() and $media = $meta_value->fetch_assoc() ) { 
$row_id = $row['post_id']; 
$media_name = $media['meta_value']; 

update_post_meta( $row_id , '_wp_attachment_metadata' , $media_name );  
}`
```

and it works I can see images/thumbnails, but when I try to edit image it says "No image data in file. Please send the image to the server again."

Comment: Yeah, WordPress documentation is horrible...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation, it is the (serialized) meta data for that image.  Basically it's a biggish associative array that describes the image.  When you use that method you have to provide all of the data values (not just the ones you know you want to change).

Changing it might look something like this:

```
$data = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id); // get the data structured
$data['width'] = 680;  // change the values you need to change
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $data );  // save it back to the db
```

You can see what the associative array looks like [in the documentation for wp_update_attachment_metadata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata)

Comment: added edit to first post, because I have no idea how to format code in reply here so annoying...

Comment: What happened when you tried it the way I described?  Did you get an error or did it simply fail to update.  Also, you can't format code in the comments, but you can highlight is by using `backticks`

Comment: I'll describe better how I tested your way. 1. Uploaded 2 new pics (standard years/date folder) 2. Defined new fodler for images uploads/images/ and moved images there 3. disabled years/months segregation 4. tested ur code and it failed to update :( As I said my code with while loop seems to works, but I'm getting error I've already quoted in my 1st post in edit

Comment: It seems like this question is experiencing some "scope creep."  I think it may be best for you to create another question to deal with the difficulty you are having and post more of your code.  I'm going to bet that the problem lies somewhere else in your code than in the part described in your original question.